# Upload user's signature to DocuSign using eSign SDK?

Tags: docusignapi, electronic-signature

I am trying to upload signature for a user using eSign SDK. I have referred [this](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Users/UserSignatures/create#sdkmethod) link for creating a signature for user. Below is my C# code:

```
var usersList = usersApi.List(Constants.accountId);

ApiClient apiClient1 = new ApiClient(Constants.basePath);
apiClient1.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Constants.userAccessToken);
UsersApi usersApi1 = new UsersApi(apiClient1.Configuration);                

if (usersList != null && usersList.Users != null && usersList.Users.Any())
{
    var activeUser = usersList.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == data["UserEmail"] && x.UserStatus.Equals("active", comparisonType: StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (activeUser != null)
    {
        UserSignature userSignature = new UserSignature()
        {
            IsDefault = "true",
            SignatureInitials = "TU",
            SignatureName = "Test User",
            ImageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ReadContent(Constants.eSignName))

        };
        List<UserSignature> userSignatures = new List<UserSignature>() { userSignature };
        UserSignaturesInformation userSignaturesInformation = new UserSignaturesInformation()
        {
            UserSignatures = userSignatures
        };
        //Create Signature
        var signResult = usersApi1.CreateSignatures(Constants.accountId, activeUser.UserId, userSignaturesInformation);
    }
}
```

After this call, the signature gets created. However, the user's signature image(passed in `ImageBase64` parameter) is not added to the created signature . The access token I have used here is from DocuSign Token generator tool from User profile. Need help in figuring out what's wrong with this request.

Comment: You mention you're using a token from the Admin user, does it work if you use a token from the actual end user? You may not be able to adopt a signature on behalf of someone else.

Comment: @Drew: I tried using access token from actual end user. This time the signature get created for user. However, the signature image(specified in ImageBase64 parameter) is not added to the created signature. I have updated the question with latest code change. Request your help in this case.

Comment: does the end user have a DocuSign account access? you have to ensure you're using that one and not a generic recipient. Even the smallest difference in the name/email could make it into a different user in the system which means - the signature would not be for them.

Comment: @InbarGazit: Yes, the user has DocuSign account access. I am able to create a signature for them. It's just that the signature image is not getting added to it.

Comment: you cannot generate it for them, they have to do it. You you need to have their userId to use JWT and make API calls on their behalf. Are you doing it this way?

Comment: @InbarGazit: Yes, I am using user's access token in ApiClient to upload the signature. It's users' call to upload the signature. That's the only reason signature profile is getting created for the user. The issue is with adding the signature image to the profile.

Comment: the token is for which user? how did you obtain it? did you use the admin user to obtain it or the end user?

Comment: @InbarGazit: The token is for end user for whom the signature needs to be uploaded. CreateSignatures method would throw exception if I used admin user's access token for API call. I have generated this token by login into end user's account and using token generator tool. I am 100% sure that the token I am using is for end user itself and that token is not the issue in this case.

Comment: ok, but you did answer earlier to Drew that it did work for one user but not the other user? can you confirm that is my understanding now. I need to isolate the issue here

Comment: @InbarGazit: Let me try to explain from beginning to avoid confusion. At the very beginning(Attempt 1) I tried to call CreateSignatures() of API SDK with Admin's access token. This API call itself threw the exception. Then(Attempt 2) I changed the access token to actual end user's. This time no exception was thrown and a signature row in UI was created which didn't contain the actual signature image(sent in parameter ImageBase64 of request). It only contained the Full Name and Initials sent through request. Attempt 2 was my answer to Drew and is the only issue I am currently facing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to take action on behalf of a different user (in your case, you want to generate and upload a signature image for a different user) you have to impersonate them when you authenticate using JWT. You have to have their userID (a GUID) as part of your API call and the user must consent to the app making call on their behalf at least once.

Comment: I don't want to take action on behalf of a different user. I am okay to use end user's access to upload signature. In fact, that's what I am doing in code mentioned in question. I am using end user's credentials to generate access token and make API call using the generated end user's access token to upload the signature saved in my local PC. While user's details like Name and Initials get added to user's profile using above code, signature image provided as ImageBase64 parameter in API don't. Above API doesn't work even when I use end user's access token to make the call.

Comment: how are you calling the API? directly ? or via one of our SDKs?